# Does the Seldon SKLearn Server support SVC models?

Tags: scikit-learn, seldon

I am trying to deploy a Seldon Deployment with a Sklearn Model. The model is a SVC classifier.

```
apiVersion: machinelearning.seldon.io/v1
kind: SeldonDeployment
metadata:
  name: test-model
  namespace: model-dev
spec:
  name: anomaly-ml
  predictors:
  - graph:
      implementation: SKLEARN_SERVER
      modelUri:  s3://test-ml
      envSecretRefName: seldon-init-container-secret
      name: classifier
    name: default
    replicas: 1
```

The Seldon classifier fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'

```
model file /mnt/models/model.joblib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/seldon-core-microservice", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('seldon-core', 'console_scripts', 'seldon-core-microservice')()
  File "/microservice/python/seldon_core/microservice.py", line 232, in main
    user_object = user_class(**parameters)
  File "/microservice/SKLearnServer.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/microservice/SKLearnServer.py", line 29, in load
    self._joblib = joblib.load(model_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 598, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 526, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1085, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1373, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1423, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'
```

Does the Seldon SKLearn Server support SVC models? 
What is going wrong here?

Any tip would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seldon presently support 0.20.3 of sklearn. See https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/issues/1813